# Javascript input element bug in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, input

I wanted to prohibit user from copy/pasting value into a field called 'Confirm Mobile No', and I have used this

```
<input type="text" name="cnfMobileNo" oncopy="return false;" onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false;">
```

This works very well in Chrome, but in firefox I see a very weird behaviour. In firefox following things happen:

- I can't press backspace key in that field
- Nor any more character's pressed get placed in that field.
- Upon refreshing the page the locked value doesn't vanish from that input type.

#### Note:

I have firefox 15.0 installed.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.oncopy, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.oncut and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onpaste. It says "Not part of specification", so it's not a bug, but each browser has its own implementation.

Comment: I can press backspace on Firefox 14 and 15, and the pressed character is placed in that field. See http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJZD/, it works for me.

Comment: @oriol Sorry, there was some other js. Have posted the new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236721/js-disabling-backspace-funtionality-in-firefox). Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here, there was some other mistake. I had a js to prevent user from entering invalid characters into a text field. This was the culript.

```
function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();   
    }
}
```

And this was preventing the backspace key. It's not a firefox bug with the `oncopy`, `onpaste` or `oncut` event.