# js disabling backspace functionality in firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, textinput, keycode

I have following javascript to prevent user from entering invalid characters into a text field. It's working well in chrome but not in firefox. It's preventing the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key to be entered in the text field in firefox.

```
function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Can anyone please have a look and propose a fix for firefox to not prevent backspace key to act on a text field ?

Probably I guess, adding the regex for the backspace character would do the job here. Does anyone know, how to add the regex for matching the <kbd>backspace</kbd>

#### Edit:

Also, the above code has supposed to interrupted with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key behaviour, I am not able to jump to next fields in the form using <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJZD/1/

```
var el=document.getElementById('cnfMobileNo');
el.onkeydown=function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    if(key===8){return;}
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Just use `if(key===8){return;}`

**Edit:**

If you want to exclude more keys, use

```
var el=document.getElementById('cnfMobileNo');
el.onkeydown=function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event,
        key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which,
        exclusions=[8,9]; /*Add exceptions here */
    if(exclusions.indexOf(key)>-1){return;}
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJZD/2/

You can know the `keyCode` of each key using `alert(key)`

(before `key = String.fromCharCode(key)`).

You could also exclude

- The arrow keys: 37,38,39,40
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>: 13
- Context menu: 93
- <kbd>Start</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>: 36,35

Comment: That perfectly helped !!! Can you also please intercept the tab key ? Have updated the question please see.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Also just for other's info [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) is a list of key codes for various keys.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure of the backspace regex but this should work too

```
$("#myInput").bind('keyup', function(){
     val1 = $(this).val();
     $(this).val(val1.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''));
});
```

You might do away with bind and directly attach keyup

Fiddle - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNAG12/VaEUe/)

Comment: This too prefectly helped. But the other solution seems more smooth as the invalid chars do not appear at all in the input field. With this solution, for a moment we can see those char's in the input field. Thanks for the help.