# html form not working after putting exception

Tags: php, javascript, html, exception

i've created exception using JS so that user are only allowed to input numbers to the html form field. this is working nicely but the problem is, the Submit button isn't working anymore. if i remove the exception code, submit button is working nicely! i can't understand where is the problem. anyone can help please? thanks in advance!

here is the exception:

```
function validateNum(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}


function validate()
{

 if( document.myForm.ic.value == "" ||
           isNaN( document.myForm.ic.value ) ||
           document.myForm.ic.value.length != 12)
   {
     alert( "Please provide your correct IC Number!" );
     document.myForm.ic.focus() ;
     return false;
   }else{
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateNum();
     if( ret == false )
     {
          return false;
     }
   }
```

here is my html form action:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="nonuum_reg.php" onsubmit="return(validate());">
```

and here is the input field & submit button:

```
 <input name="ic" type="text" id="ic" maxlength="12" size="45" onkeypress='validateNum(event)'/>

<input type="submit" value="Apply" />
```

Comment: You can't recall validateNum() inside validate() function which is called by onsubmit of form, because the event is different. Try my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one as my explanation on my comment on your question:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="nonuum_reg.php" onsubmit="validate(event);">
    <input name="ic" type="text" id="ic" maxlength="12" size="45" onkeypress='validateNum(event)'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>
<script>
    function validateNum(evt) {
        var theEvent = evt;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode( key );
        var regex = /[0-9]|\./;

        if( !regex.test(key) ) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    function validate(evt){
        if( document.myForm.ic.value == "" || isNaN( document.myForm.ic.value ) || document.myForm.ic.value.length != 12) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            alert( "Please provide your correct IC Number!" );
            document.myForm.ic.focus() ;
            return false;
        } 
    }
</script>
```

You should still create validation on your PHP controller to prevent if users turn off javascript on theirs browser.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) let me give a try & then i'll let you know :)

Comment: can i ask for little more help? how can i modify the code to validate email??

 'function validateEmail()
{
 
   var emailID = document.myForm.mail.value;
   atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
   dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
   if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
   {
       alert("Please enter correct email ID")
       document.myForm.mail.focus() ;
       return false;
   }
   return( true );
}'

Comment: and 'function validate(event){if( document.myForm.mail.value == "" ){
   alert( "Please provide your valid Email!" );
   document.myForm.mail.focus() ;
   return false;
    }else{
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateEmail();
     if( ret == false )
  {
          return false;
     }
  return true;
   }}'

Comment: awesome!! thanks again :) & realy sorry for late reply.. you really helped me to reduce my pain :) have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a return true in you =r else close

```
...

else{
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateNum();
     if( ret == false )
     {
          return false;
     }

   return true;
}
```

...

This should also help you (not the same issue but same code)[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236721/js-disabling-backspace-functionality-in-firefox):

Comment: aha should have tested before posting, sorry. I dont know if your are familiar with jQuery and YUI. They have really nice validation methods my favorite is. jQuery UI ->http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: thanks @bleuscyther for your concern:)  by the way, its solve already :)