# Firefox onkeypress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have creating a function that is working great on chrome but doesn't work in Firefox.

The function only allows the user is input numbers, in chrome it will also let you use"CTRL + V", Backspace, Delete and Arrow keys. However in Firefox it wont allow any of those only numbers

**HTML**

```
<input onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" min="1" max="9999999999">
```

**Jquery**

```
//maxlength input stop
function maxLengthCheck(object) {
  if (object.value.length > object.max.length)
    object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.max.length)
}

//is input numeric
function isNumeric (evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode (key);
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if ( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: `theEvent.returnValue` isn't supported in Firefox at all -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue

Comment: Check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236721/js-disabling-backspace-functionality-in-firefox