# Regex is not working with name space and backspace in Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried this in my code, but is not working in Firefox browser.

My code is this

```
name: new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z \b]*$")
```

It's working fine in Chrome, but is not working in Firefox Browser. It only works character or space if I give to backspace it's not working. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Check [js disabling backspace functionality in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236721/js-disabling-backspace-functionality-in-firefox)

Comment: Please share the part of your code that uses the regexp, the input, the current output and the expected output. That will help us help you

Comment: Try dbl backslash b Since it is in a quote. \\b